# Semantic version type on PG 11.5 deployed on RDS. ltree?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I've got some semantic version details to store, and figured a dedicated type would be a bit help with searches and sorts. At least one implementation exists:

https://github.com/theory/pg-semver

This is not supported on RDS. why we're on RDS. Is there an alternative that's RDS enabled? I'm considering either `ltree` or simply using a `text` or `citext` and grinding out the necessary queries and sorts, as needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use an array of integers e.g. version `1.2.3` would be `array[1,2,3]`.

Such an array compares (and sorts) correctly. To format it as a string, you could write some simple functions.

Parsing is simple as well: `string_to_array('1.2.3', '.')::int[]`

Comment: Interesting suggestion, I hadn't thought of that. I'll experiment with what the queries look like. I'd love a real semantic versioning type....but it's AWS letting me down here, not Postgres.